# How to output all the resources of one type in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a bunch of `aws_ecr_repositories` defined in my Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "nginx_images" {
  name = "nginx-test"
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "oracle_images" {
  name = "oracle-test"
}
```

I want to be able to have an output that can list all the `aws_ecr_repository` resources into one output. This is what I tried:

```
output "ecr_repository_urls" {
  value = "[${aws_ecr_repository.*.repository_url}]"
}
```

This does not work because Terraform does not seem to allow wildcards on the resource names. Is it possible to have an output like this? My current solution is to just list outputs for every resource defined.

Comment: Here's the request for the functionality in the question: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19931

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Terraform's splat syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-other-resources) is for keeping track of each thing created by a resource using the [`count` meta parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#meta-parameters).

If you want to be able to get at all of the respoitory URLs you could have a single `aws_ecr_repository` resource and use the `count` meta parameter with something like this:

```
variable "images" {
  default = [
    "nginx-test",
    "oracle-test",
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "images" {
  count = "${length(var.images)}"
  name  = "${var.images[count.index]}"
}

output "ecr_repository_urls" {
  value = "[${aws_ecr_repository.images.*.repository_url}]"
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind if that list order changes (whether that is re-ordering, adding something in the middle or beginning of the list, or removing something from the list that isn't the last item in the list) then you may end up with the unintended consequence of recreating repositories you didn't intend to.

Comment: How to output all variables, not just repository_url?

Answer (score 2):

You can combine them manually as a list:

```
output "ecr_repository_urls" {
  value = ["${aws_ecr_repository.nginx_images.repository_url}", "${aws_ecr_repository.oracle_images.repository_url}"]
}
```

Although it probably won't be pretty in code.

You could also do something like this:

```
variable "ecr_repos" {
  default = {
    "0" = "foo"
    "1" = "bar"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "images" {
  count = "${length(var.ecr_repos)}"
  name  = "${lookup(var.ecr_repos,count.index)}-test"
}

output "ecr_repository_urls" {
  value = "${aws_ecr_repository.images.*.repository_url}"
}
```

But the problem is if the list order changes it's going to recreate resources and get really ugly really fast since each repo is assigned to an index number.