# How to concatenate strings in Terraform output with for loop?

Tags: terraform, terratest

I have multiple `aws_glue_catalog_table` resources and I want to create a single `output` that loops over all resources to show the S3 bucket location of each one. The purpose of this is to test if I am using the correct `location` (because it is a concatenation of variables) for each resource in Terratest. I cannot use `aws_glue_catalog_table.*` or `aws_glue_catalog_table.[]` because Terraform does not allow to reference a resource without specifying its name.

So I created a `variable "table_names"` with `r1`, `r2`, `rx`. Then, I can loop over the names. I want to create the string `aws_glue_catalog_table.r1.storage_descriptor[0].location` dynamically, so I can check if the `location` is correct.

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "r1" {
  name          = "r1"
  database_name = var.db_name
  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/${var.environment}-config/r1"
  }
...
}
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "rX" {
  name          = "rX"
  database_name = var.db_name
  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/${var.environment}-config/rX"
  }
}

variable "table_names" {
  description = "The list of Athena table names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["r1", "r2", "r3", "rx"]
}
output "athena_tables" {
  description = "Athena tables"
  value = [for n in var.table_names : n]
}
```

**First attempt:** I tried to create an `output "athena_tables_location"` with the syntax `aws_glue_catalog_table.${table}` but does does.

```
output "athena_tables_location" {
  // HOW DO I ITERATE OVER ALL TABLES?
  value = [for t in var.table_names : aws_glue_catalog_table.${t}.storage_descriptor[0].location"]
}
```

**Second attempt:** I tried to create a `variable "table_name_locations"` but IntelliJ already shows an error `${t}` in the for loop `[for t in var.table_names : "aws_glue_catalog_table.${t}.storage_descriptor[0].location"]`.

```
variable "table_name_locations" {
  description = "The list of Athena table locations"
  type        = list(string)
  // THIS ALSO DOES NOT WORK
  default     = [for t in var.table_names : "aws_glue_catalog_table.${t}.storage_descriptor[0].location"]
}
```

How can I list all table locations in the `output` and then test it with Terratest?
Once I can iterate over the tables and collect the S3 location I can do the following test using Terratest:

```
athenaTablesLocation := terraform.Output(t, terraformOpts, "athena_tables_location")
assert.Contains(t, athenaTablesLocation, "s3://rX/test-config/rX",)
```

Comment: Try: `aws_glue_catalog_table[t].storage_descriptor[0].location`

Comment: I have to do `aws_glue_catalog_table.[t].storage_descriptor[0].location`, with `.` after `aws_glue_catalog_table`. But `I get the error `<number> expected, got '['`

Comment: No, a dot before the `[` is invalid syntax, which is why you get that error. So you definitely do not have to do the `.` after `aws_glue_catalog_table`. Did you actually try what I suggested?

Comment: yes, I tried. If I dop't use the `.` I get the error `Unresolved reference storage_descriptor`

Comment: when I use `aws_glue_catalog_table[t].` and do Ctrl + space, IntelliJ suggests autocompletion with the names of the tables `r1` ... `rX`. IntelliJ thinks that I am on the same level of the `aws_glue_catalog_table` without `[t]`. BTW I am using a golang plugin for IntelliJ. So I guess the problem is not IntelliJ. It is still the syntax.

Comment: Instead of defining multiple `aws_glue_catalog_table` resources, I think you need to define a single `aws_glue_catalog_table` resource with a `for_each` argument https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html Then you will have a list of `aws_glue_catalog_table` resources you can iterate over later instead of separate resources with different names.

Comment: ummm, kind of cannot do that because each `aws_glue_catalog_table` has different collumns

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839051/how-to-output-all-the-resources-of-one-type-in-terraform

Comment: ummm. it seems that I need to generate the resources in a loop like you said. the question that you mentioned uses `*` after the second level of the resource `"[${aws_ecr_repository.images.*.repository_url}]"`. Terraform does not allow me to use `*` on the first level. So I have to figure out how to create the columns properly for different resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an unusual mix of static and dynamic here: you've statically defined a fixed number of `aws_glue_catalog_table` resources but you want to use them dynamically based on the value of an input variable.

Terraform doesn't allow dynamic references to resources because its execution model requires building a dependency graph between all of the objects, and so it needs to know which exact resources are involved in a particular expression. However, you can in principle build your own single value that includes all of these objects and then dynamically choose from it:

```
locals {
  tables = {
    r1 = aws_glue_catalog_table.r1
    r2 = aws_glue_catalog_table.r2
    r3 = aws_glue_catalog_table.r3
    # etc
  }
}

output "table_locations" {
  value = {
    for t in var.table_names : t => local.tables[t].storage_descriptor[0].location
  }
}
```

With this structure Terraform can see that `output "table_locations"` depends on `local.tables` and `local.tables` depends on *all* of the relevant resources, and so the evaluation order will be correct.

---

However, it also seems like your table definitions are systematic based on `var.table_names` and so could potentially benefit from being dynamic themselves. You could achieve that using the [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) feature to declare multiple instances of a single resource:

```
variable "table_names" {
  description = "Athena table names to create"
  type        = set(string)
  default     = ["r1", "r2", "r3", "rx"]
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "all" {
  for_each = var.table_names

  name          = each.key
  database_name = var.db_name
  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://${var.bucket_name}/${var.environment}-config/${each.key}"
  }
  ...
}

output "table_locations" {
  value = {
    for k, t in aws_glue_catalog_table.all : k => t.storage_descriptor[0].location
  }
}
```

In this case `aws_glue_catalog_table.all` represents all of the tables together as a single resource with multiple instances, each one identified by the table name. `for_each` resources appear in expressions as maps, so this will declare resource instances with addresses like this:

- `aws_glue_catalog_table.all["r1"]`
- `aws_glue_catalog_table.all["r2"]`
- `aws_glue_catalog_table.all["r3"]`
- ...

Because this is already a map, this time we don't need the extra step of constructing the map in a local value, and can instead just access this map directly to build the output value, which will be a map from table name to storage location:

```
{
  r1 = "s3://BUCKETNAME/ENVNAME-config/r1"
  r2 = "s3://BUCKETNAME/ENVNAME-config/r2"
  r3 = "s3://BUCKETNAME/ENVNAME-config/r3"
  # ...
}
```

In this example I've assumed that all of the tables are identical aside from their names, which I expect isn't true in practice but I was going only by what you included in the question. If the tables *do* need to have different settings then you can change `var.table_names` to instead be a `variable "tables"` whose type is a map of object type where the values describe the differences between the tables, but that's a different topic kinda beyond the scope of this question, so I won't get into the details of that here.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the first approach. The second seems ideal to achieve DRY. But each one of my tables have different columns. I don't know how I would refactore to have a different set of columns for each table.

Comment: awesome @Martin. the first solution worked perfectly. The weird thing is that IntelliJ does not recognize `storage_descriptor[0].location` in the end of the expression `for t in var.table_names : t => local.tables[t].storage_descriptor[0].location`. It might be the GO plugin that I am using. I was suspicious in the begin but I gave a try and it worked! Big thanks!